# Get json data chield value

Tags: json

I want to get chield coordinates data from the json data.

I used this code but I get an error.

```
console.log(data.features.geometry[0].coordinates);
```

Here the data is a ajax result.

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {"type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [[28.9681060393493,
              41.007415243341],
            [28.9679918512905,
              41.00729272796],
            [28.9679314102614,
              41.0073143412354],
            [28.9680128968503,
              41.007414681345],
            [28.9680423242404,
              41.0074515099658],
            [ 28.9681094965952,
              41.0074197765024],
            [28.9681060393493,
              41.007415243341]]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "f1": 110006283,
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You probably want: console.log(data.features.geometry.coordinates[0]);

Comment: I get coordinates undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**as features is array and geometry is object**

```
console.log(data.features[0].geometry.coordinates);
```

**here is iterated code**

```
var myloop = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]

for(var i = 0;i<myloop.length ; i++){
console.log(myloop[i][0],myloop[i][1])
}
```

Comment: I get an array didn't get coordinates

Comment: yeah you will get coordinate array,if you want co-ordinates you must iterate it